# How to have two input fields with drag and drop functionality in selectize.js?

Tags: selectize.js

**Desired Functionality**

- Two input fields that both have drag and drop functionality.
- With the generated `'value'` div beneath each input field.

**Current Functionality**

Four generated `'value'` divs are being created instead of two.

**Plugin Demo** (select the `Plugins` tab and scroll to `"drag_drop"`)

http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js

**What I've Tried:**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/E72q5/5/

**HTML Form**

```
<!-- simple html form - a container with left and right divs -->

<div class="my_form_page_content">
<form id="my_form_name" name="my_form_name">
<div class="my_form_container">
<div class="my_form_left">
<p>field one</p>
<p>field two</p>
</div>
<div class="my_form_right">
<div class="input_wrapper">
<input type="text" id="input-sortable-1" class="input-sortable demo-default" value="input 1 value, lala1, lala1a">
</div>
<div class="input_wrapper">
<input type="text" id="input-sortable-2" class="input-sortable demo-default" value="input 2 value, lala2, lala2a">
</div>
</div>
<div class="my_form_button">
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
// aim:  to have a unique 'value' div beneath each input field. 

// selectize drag and drop functionality

$('.input-sortable').selectize({
plugins: ['drag_drop'],
delimiter: ',',
persist: false,
create: function(input) {
return {
value: input,
text: input
}
}
});

// the js that should add a 'value' div after each input box

$(function() {
var $wrapper = $('.input_wrapper');
// show current input values
$('select.selectized,input.selectized', $wrapper).each(function() {
var $container = $('<div>').addClass('value').html('Current Value: ');
var $value = $('<span>').appendTo($container);
var $input = $(this);
var update = function(e) { $value.text(JSON.stringify($input.val())); }

$(this).on('change', update);
update();

$container.insertAfter($wrapper);
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have done a fiddle as per your input.

http://jsfiddle.net/Shinov/csNgy/

```
 $input.parents(".field-row:first").append($container)
```